# Non-existent file for the CFBundleExecutable key xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

When i archive build and want to  export this error received in xcode 8.1. How i resolve this.This is working fine in xcode 7. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolve the error. I simply uncheck the Bitcode option when creating builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code of static library or project which builds **ABC.bundle** file then select the target which builds the **ABC.bundle** search for **plist** in **Build Settings** and remove any paths specified for **inof.plist file** then build the target and now use the **ABC.bundle** error is gone.

[image: info.plist file]